# Is there any way to gain an evasion reaction when using All Out Attacks

Tags: dark-heresy-2e

I'm playing a character with a focus on all out attack actions. This allows me to hit hard, but comes with the downside of being incapable of evading attacks. In general there are three types of melee builds in Dark Heresy, and by late game all three tend to put out similar offense, but mine still suffers massively in defense.

Is there any way to gain access to an evasion while using All out attacks? It seems odd that melee characters either have two evasions or none with no middle ground, and it'd be odd for one build to end up being so much worse than the others. Have I missed anything?

Comment: How have you built around the All Out Attack?

Comment: Crushing/Hammer Blow, Furious Assault, etc.